# How to specify GPU limit docker swarm using docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

How to specify GPU, CPU & Memory limit using docker compose?

For this case i have follow instructions at (https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/).

Using :

```
$ apt-get install nvidia-container-runtime
```

I'm also check it with :

```
$ docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
```

Examples `docker-compose.yaml` :

```
version: '2'
   ...
   services:
        ...
        my-service:
            ...
            deploy:
              resources:
                reservations:
                  generic_resources:
                    - discrete_resource_spec:
                        kind: 'gpu'
                        value: 1
                limits:
                      cpus: '4'
                      memory: 4096M
         another-service:
             ...
             deploy:
                resources:
                   limits:
                      cpus: '0.001'
                      memory: 50M
```